# Listview not displaying all the time

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a problem with displaying List view. We are having an customized item delegate for this list where we overwrite the paint event.The Problem is the list does not display on UI When it is loaded.The list is displayed when we generate an mouse Press event in list.Please Give your Ideas and suggestion to solve this.

I am adding customized delegate code for your better understanding.

```
    void CItemDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();

    if( option.state & QStyle::State_Sunken )
    {
        painter->fillRect( option.rect, option.palette.highlight() );
    }
    if( m_connectionStatus && ( m_selectedIndex == index.row() ) )
    {
        QPixmap selectionIndicator = icons[10];
        painter->drawPixmap( option.rect.width() - selectionIndicator.width() - 10, option.rect.top() + option.rect.height() / 2 - selectionIndicator.height() / 2, selectionIndicator );
    }

    // Draw the icon
    QVariantList fields = index.data().toList();
    QPixmap  icon = icons[fields[IconIndex].toInt()];

    painter->drawPixmap( 14, option.rect.top() + option.rect.height() / 2 - icon.height() / 2, icon );

    QFont f( painter->font() );
    f.setPixelSize( 23 ) ;
    f.setBold( true );
    painter->setFont( f );

    // Draw the error description text, truncated if necessary
    static const int TextLeftMargin = 80;
    static const int TextTopBottomMargin = 25;

    QString elidedDescription = painter->fontMetrics().elidedText( fields[Description].toString(), Qt::ElideRight, 352 );
    painter->drawText( option.rect.adjusted( TextLeftMargin, TextTopBottomMargin, 0, 0 ),  Qt::AlignLeft, elidedDescription );

    // Divider
    QRect dividerRect = option.rect;
    dividerRect.setTop( dividerRect.bottom() );
    QLinearGradient gradient( 0, 0, option.rect.width() / 2, 0 );
    gradient.setColorAt( 0, QColor( 144, 144, 144, 0 ) );
    gradient.setColorAt( 1, QColor( 144, 144, 144, 255 ) );
    gradient.setSpread( QGradient::ReflectSpread );
    painter->fillRect( dividerRect, gradient );

    painter->restore();


}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call `QWidget::update()` function to force repainting your list view after it comes up?

Comment: I tried this also.But still i have issue

Comment: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemview.html#update